# Linux ioctl() with a virtual device

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, ioctl, evdev

I want to create a virtual device on my Linux system. I am using libevdev. The first thing I do is to mirror an existing device. The new virtual device with all the same event types, event codes etc. is created:

```cpp
libevdev* dev = nullptr;
int fd = open("/dev/input/event16", O_RDONLY);
libevdev_new_from_fd(fd, &dev);

libevdev_uinput* uidev = nullptr;
int uifd = open("/dev/uinput", O_RDWR);
err = libevdev_uinput_create_from_device(dev, uifd, &uidev);
```

After above lines of code a new file `event17` is created in a directory `/dev/input`.

The next thing I want to do is to call `ioctl()`:

```cpp
int fd = open("/dev/input/event17", O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd, REQUEST_VALUE, &data);
```

but `ioctl` ends up with a *connection timeout*.

So the question is: how to invoke `ioctl()` on the virtual devices? Is it even possible? Is there any functionality on Linux kernel which allows virtual devices to behave as they were real devices?

Comment: What would you expect it to do if it "worked"?

Comment: What ioctl are you trying to send and what is its purpose? What device is it (keyboard, mouse, etc.)? Do you have a working example of the code that we can test to reproduce this behavior?

Comment: Request for `ioctl` is `EVIOCSFF` and `data` is `ff_effect`. I want to handle force feedback effects.

Comment: I believe best place for these kind of advanced Linux questions are good old mailing lists.